# No puedo encontrar mi imagen

Tags: html, nodejs, img, handlebars

Hola hoy una pregunta muy básica, pero de verdad que entiendo porque no funciona, estoy tratando de llamar una imagen desde html con handlebars, pero no renderiza o la encuentra.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No obstante estoy 100% seguro de que mi imagen está en donde le apunto, no sé si estoy apuntando bien, y tambien tengo por seguro que estoy obteniendo el nombre de la imagen, justo la imprimo abajo para estar seguro de ello.

```
<div>
<img style=' width:280px;height:200px;' src='../../public/uploads/{{img}}'>
{{img}}
</div>



// Publics
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // esto es lo que tenía y lo que agregué
app.use(express.static('public/uploads'));
```

mi proyecto está así:

```
/index.js
/views/projects/mivista.hbs
/public/uploads/42c......896.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la creación de tu server usaste el middleware para hacer la carpeta `public` pública?

`app.use(express.static('public/uploads'));`

Si es así, entonces no es necesario que hagas esto:
`<img style=' width:280px;height:200px;' src='../../public/uploads/{{img}}'>`

Sino sería algo así:
`<img style=' width:280px;height:200px;' src='{{img}}'>`

O si deseas que todo lo que esté en `public` sea público:

`app.use(express.static('public'));`

`<img style=' width:280px;height:200px;' src='uploads/{{img}}'>`

Comment: ok dejame intentar

Comment: sigo sin resivirlo, ahorita actualizo y agrego lo que tenía en mi server.

Comment: Extraño, a menos que se necesite especificar más:`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/')));`

Comment: bien raro, pero ya estuvo usé > app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/')));